# Declaring foldl ( from left) in terms of foldr (from right)

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, ocaml, folding

I have foldl:

```
let rec foldl f lst acc = match lst with
  | [] -> acc
  | hd::tl -> foldl f lst (f hd acc)
```

and I have foldr:

```
let rec foldr f lst acc = match lst with 
  | [] -> acc
  | hd::tl -> f hd (foldr f tl acc);;
```

I want to declare foldl using foldr.

How could this be done?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? In Haskell right folds are preferred, but that's because of the lazily evaluated nature of Haskell. In OCaml, evaluation is eager, so the tail-recursiveness of a left fold makes it _much_ more common compared to a right fold.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things you have to bear in mind is commutativity. For operations like addition or multiplication, it doesn't matter.

```
(((1 * 2) * 3) * 4)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
(1 * (2 * (3 * 4)))
```

But, if we consider something like *subtraction*...

```
(((1 - 2) - 3) - 4)
```

Is definitely not equivalent to:

```
(1 - (2 - (3 - 4)))
```

```
# (((1 - 2) - 3) - 4);;
- : int = -8
# (1 - (2 - (3 - 4)));;
- : int = -2
```

Fortunately, we can flip a function that takes two arguments. The standard library defines `Fun.flip`, but it's easily implemented.

```
# let flip f a b = f b a;;
val flip : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'b -> 'a -> 'c = <fun>
```

So, we can flip `f` and reverse the input list:

```
foldr (flip (-)) [4; 3; 2; 1] 0
flip (-) 4 (foldr (flip (-)) [3; 2; 1] 0)
flip (-) 4 (flip (-) 3 (foldr (flip (-)) [2; 1] 0))
flip (-) 4 (flip (-) 3 (flip (-) 2 (foldr (flip (-)) [1] 0)))
flip (-) 4 (flip (-) 3 (flip (-) 2 (flip (-) 1 (foldr (flip (-)) [] 0))))
flip (-) 4 (flip (-) 3 (flip (-) 2 (flip (-) 1 0)))
flip (-) 4 (flip (-) 3 (flip (-) 2 (0 - 1)))
flip (-) 4 (flip (-) 3 (flip (-) 2 ~-1))
flip (-) 4 (flip (-) 3 (~-1 - 2))
flip (-) 4 (flip (-) 3 ~-3)
flip (-) 4 (~-3 - 3)
flip (-) 4 ~-6
~-6 - 4
~-10
```

And checking our logic:

```
# List.fold_left (-) 0 [1; 2; 3; 4];;
- : int = -10
```

*The same logic can be applied to implementing `foldr` in terms of `foldl`.*

Answer (score 0):

Informally, according to your definitions,

```js
foldl (+) z [a;b;c;d] = (d+(c+(b+(a+z))))
foldr (*) n [a;b;c;d] = (a*(b*(c*(d*n))))
```

and so we need

```js
foldl (+) z   [a;b;c;d]
 = foldr (*) n [a;b;c;d]     z
 = (a*(b*(c*(d*n))))         z
 =    (b*(c*(d*n)))       (a+z)
 =       (c*(d*n))     (b+(a+z))
 =      ...
 =             n (d+(c+(b+(a+z))))
 =               (d+(c+(b+(a+z))))
```

and thus it must be

```js
   (a*r) z = r (a+z)
   n     z = z
```

i.e., in pseudocode,

```js
foldl plus z xs  =  foldr mult n xs z
  where
  n        = { z => z }
  mult a r = { z => r (plus a z) }
```

Now you can write this in your syntax.

---

Note that the standard [`fold_left`](https://courses.cs.cornell.edu/cs3110/2021sp/textbook/hop/fold_left.html) uses the flipped order of accumulation compared to yours (which was also used in the previous version of this answer).